# In Xcode how can I detect the bump between two iphones?

Tags: iphone, ios5, bump

I want to do an app like Bump, where touching two iPhone I can detect them, does anybody know how can I detect the phisical bump of the iPhone?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does "bump" technology work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3383447/how-does-bump-technology-work)

Comment: This answer is with Bump API and I want to know only how to detect the Bump without their Api, thanks for your anwser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I also started out looking to do this myself, honestly using the Bump API was quick and painless...and it just worked.  I would highly recommend that you check it out before trying to "roll your own"...

Answer (score 5):

Use a combination of accelerometer events, geolocation and time.

1. Detect a physical bump in your app.  Use the accelerometer to detect motion and sudden stopping of that motion.
2. Upload the bump event to your central server.  A bump event includes geolocation and time.
3. On the central server determine if there is a matching bump event with similar attributes: time and location.  If there are conflicts, such as in a crowd at a conference, simply ask the users to bump again.
4. If there is a matching unique bump event, notify both clients that a bump has occurred and match them up for further processing.

Also, see [How does "bump" technology work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3383447/how-does-bump-technology-work)