# Is it possible to wirelessly transfer HD video from iPhone to iPhone without wifi and without 4G or 3G?

Tags: iphone, video, ios5, bluetooth, video-streaming

I'm guessing bluetooth.

What are the transfer speeds?

It would have to work on iPhones which are not jailbroken, although I'm still curious about how it could work better on jailbroken ones.

Comment: Couldn't you just connect it to the computer with a cord?

Comment: :) yeah, no cord and no other computer available, say you're in the desert. Pointing the first iPhone camera toward the screen of the second iPhone would do it but I want decent quality.

Comment: In the desert camera can't see screen. reflection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GameKit `GKSession` class supports connecting to nearby instances of the same app using both Wi-Fi and Bluetooth.  The choice of transport is completely automatic and hidden by the API.  So you could use that to transfer data between nearby devices.  I don't know what the transfer speed is like though.  Probably not very good.

Answer (score -1):

I guess, via ["Bump Technology".](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3383485/790794)

Comment: bump technology for video streaming will introduce a latency that may hinder the user experience, something that you dont necessarily feel when you bump.

Comment: doesn't bump use internet connectivity which we don't have here since no wifi and no 3G or 4G?

Comment: @AlexisPribula :I have heared about this technology but haven't gone through in depth about Bump Technology regarding how does it exactly work? I will update soon as I gone through it.